# avoid highlight next letter when right arrow pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea with keydown event,when I typed in the textarea and placed the cursor at the middle and move the right arrow it highlights the next letter, is there possible way not to highlight the next letter? For left arrow it works fine it does not highlight the letter. Thank you in advance.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
  <div class="row">
   <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" ng-keydown="keyPress();"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(scope) {
  scope.keyPress = function(){
     var code = event.which;
       if (code == 37) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.activeElement.selectionStart--;
            document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
        }
        if (code == 39) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.activeElement.selectionStart++;
            document.activeElement.selectionEnd++;
        }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code when the when you press the left arrow key you are decrementing the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` both the properties. When you place your cursor in the middle of the string the both `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` will be equal i.e will have the position of the character just before the cursor.
So lets say `selectionStart=4` and `selectionEnd=4` so when you decrement `selectionStart` it becomes `3` and then decrementing `selectionEnd` it will also become `3` so they both point to same location therefore no selection. But in right arrow press its works a bit differently, when you increment `selectionStart` it becomes `5` also it will increment the value of `selectionEnd` because `selectionEnd` can never be less than `selectionStart`(as end can not be behind start) so `selectionEnd` becomes `5` and then incrementing `selectionEnd` it will become `6` so now you have `selectionStart=5` and `selectionEnd=6`. So you have one character selected according to this and hence the behaviour.

So in order to achieve what you want you can just comment out the `document.activeElement.selectionEnd++;` line of code in you right arrow press handler. Belwo is a demo

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope", function(scope) {
  scope.keyPress = function(){
     var code = event.which;
       if (code == 37) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.activeElement.selectionStart--;
            document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
        }
        if (code == 39) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.activeElement.selectionStart++;
            //document.activeElement.selectionEnd++;

        }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
  <div class="row">
   <textarea name="text" unselectable="on" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" ng-keydown="keyPress();"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

[MDN SelectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart)

[MDN SelectionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionEnd)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there any way for the left arrow to stop when it reaches at the beginning of the letter?

Comment: stop as in? Didnt get you. Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by stop.

Comment: i mean when you placed the cursor at the beginning and pressed the left arrow it goes to the end of the letter, do you have any idea where i can put the cursor on just the beginning when I pressed the let arrow? thank you

Comment: So you are saying if there are more than one words typed and then you press the left arrow it goes to the end of the previous word. You instead want it to go the the beginning? Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes I just want the cursor to stay on the beginning if the cursor is on the beginning of the first letter. if you pressed the left arrow key.

Comment: so it doesnt goes back at the end of the word. hope its possible.

Comment: for example i typed the word "apple" and placed the cursor before "a" when I press the left arrow the cursor should stay on its position if it is on the beginning.

Comment: for that what you can do is set `selectionStart` to 0 it will always remain at first position only.

Answer (score 0):

For my follow up question in the comment, I managed to do it by this.

```
if (code == 37) {
            document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
              var test = false;
             if(test == false){
            //  document.activeElement.selectionStart--;
              document.activeElement.selectionEnd--;
              if(document.activeElement.selectionStart == 0){
                 test = true;

                 document.activeElement.selectionEnd = 0;
                 document.activeElement.selectionStart = 0;
              }
        }
```